# Error: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined", logout function REACTJS

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, axios, logout

[image: screen capture when I click on logout after login]I have a php code (logout.php) which destroys the user session. I want to call my handleLogOut function when the user click on 'log out'(at the end of the code) in the NavBar. If the status response is 200, the session is closed and the user is redirected to my login page. I have the error : "navBar.js:24 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined".
what can I add or change in my code please?

navBar.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

    import { MDBNavbar,  MDBNavbarNav, MDBNavItem, MDBNavLink, MDBNavbarToggler, MDBCollapse, MDBDropdown,
    MDBDropdownToggle, MDBDropdownMenu, MDBDropdownItem,  } from "mdbreact";
    import axios from "axios";
    import { Redirect} from 'react-router';


class NavbarPage extends Component {
state = {
  isOpen: false,
  logOut: false,
};

handleLogOut () {
  axios.get("http://localhost:8888/login/logout.php")

  .then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    this.setState({logOut: true});
  }.bind(this))

  .catch((error) => {
    if(error.response.status === 403){
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}

toggleCollapse = () => {
  this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
}

render() {
  const bgRed = {backgroundColor: 'rgb(83, 4, 4)'};
  const{logOut} = this.state;


  if(logOut){
    return <Redirect to="/login"/>;
  }

  return (
      <MDBNavbar style={bgRed} dark expand="md" scrolling fixed="top">

        <MDBNavbarToggler onClick={this.toggleCollapse} />
        <MDBCollapse id="navbarCollapse3" isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
          <MDBNavbarNav left>
          <MDBNavItem active  className="M">
              <MDBNavLink to="/acceuil"><strong>MyBibli</strong></MDBNavLink>
            </MDBNavItem>
            <MDBNavItem active>
              <MDBNavLink to="/mesLivres">Mes livres</MDBNavLink>
            </MDBNavItem>
            <MDBNavItem>
              <MDBNavLink to="/ajoutLivre">Ajouter un livre</MDBNavLink>
            </MDBNavItem>
            </MDBNavbarNav>

            <MDBNavItem>
              <MDBDropdown>
                <MDBDropdownToggle nav caret>
                  <div className="d-none d-md-inline">My account</div>
                </MDBDropdownToggle>
                <MDBDropdownMenu className="dropdown-default">
                  <MDBDropdownItem href="#!">Gérer mon compte</MDBDropdownItem>
                  <MDBDropdownItem href="#!" onClick = {this.handleLogOut} >Log Out</MDBDropdownItem>
                </MDBDropdownMenu>
              </MDBDropdown>
            </MDBNavItem>


          </MDBNavbarNav>
        </MDBCollapse>
      </MDBNavbar>
    );
  }
}

export default NavbarPage;
```

logout.php:

```
<?php   
        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['User'])){
        session_destroy();
        http_response_code(200);
        }
        else {
        http_response_code(403);
        }
?>
```

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(error)` in your catch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the error object has and attribute called "response"

```
.catch((error) => {
  if(error.response && error.response.status === 403){
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Most likely the code snippet above will not fix your issue entirely but hopefully gets you closer to the solution.